# how to connect to Bluetooth 2.1 enabled device with iphone 5 in ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, eaaccessory

I have a medical device which is Bluetooth enabled with version 2.1+EDR.

I want to integrate the device inside my application. I am targeting mainly the iOS devices with BLE/Bluetooth 4.0 .

Any idea the latest iOS devices will be compatible with mentioned medical device. IF so how will be the approach.(means I can use Corebluetooth ,EAAccessory framework or I have enroll the MFi Program).

Answer (score 0):

If the device is Bluetooth 4/Bluetooh Low Energy (also known as Bluetooth Smart) the you can use Core bluetooth. If it is Bluetooth 2.1 then you need to go through the MFI program and embed an Apple chip in your device I order to identify it to iOS and use the external accessory framework

Comment: Thanks Paul for quick response,

Comment: Are you sure that I have to go through MFI program as its mentioned in MFI FAQ that

Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth Low Energy/BTLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported by iOS are not part of the MFi Program.

Comment: BLE/BT 4 does not go through MFI, you can use it with CoreBluetooth directly. If your device is BT 2.1 only then you need to go through MFI